# Spring Boot GraalVM Native Image JRT File System is Disabled Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I´m trying to convert a spring boot 2.x project to spring boot 3.1.3 and compile it with the native profile for the graalvm.

I have followed this guide so far: https://softwaremill.com/how-to-migrate-a-spring-boot-app-to-a-native-image/#before-migration

I was able compile and run the project with spring AOT enabled, generating the reachability metadata and after that successfully built the native image. My current env is: W10 22H2 x64 | openJDK 17.0.8 | graalVM CE 22.3.3 | MSVC 14.16.27023.

When i run the executable it starts very quickly, but when i try to make any requests to the http endpoints of the application i get the following error:

```
15:36:01.330 [ERROR] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:960)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:621)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:359)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsPlatformThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsPlatformThreads.java:178)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:663)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:368)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerMappings(DispatcherServlet.java:602)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:508)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:603)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
        at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.github.classgraph.ClassGraphException: Uncaught exception during scan
        at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1570)
        at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1587)
        at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1600)
        at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.scanForWebJars(WebJarAssetLocator.java:188)
        at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.<init>(WebJarAssetLocator.java:210)
        at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.<init>(WebJarAssetLocator.java:194)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.WebJarsResourceResolver.<init>(WebJarsResourceResolver.java:63)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceChainRegistration.getResourceResolvers(ResourceChainRegistration.java:114)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration.getRequestHandler(ResourceHandlerRegistration.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry.getRequestHandler(ResourceHandlerRegistry.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry.getHandlerMapping(ResourceHandlerRegistry.java:168)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:589)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport__BeanDefinitions.lambda$getResourceHandlerMappingInstanceSupplier$7(WebMvcConfigurationSupport__BeanDefinitions.java:172)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingBiFunction.apply(ThrowingBiFunction.java:68)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingBiFunction.apply(ThrowingBiFunction.java:54)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.lambda$get$2(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:202)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.invokeBeanSupplier(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.get(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception while invoking method "list"
        at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.utils.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:268)
        at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.utils.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:301)
        at io.github.classgraph.ModuleReaderProxy.list(ModuleReaderProxy.java:107)
        at io.github.classgraph.ClasspathElementModule.scanPaths(ClasspathElementModule.java:286)
        at io.github.classgraph.Scanner$5.processWorkUnit(Scanner.java:1095)
        at io.github.classgraph.Scanner$5.processWorkUnit(Scanner.java:1089)
        at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.concurrency.WorkQueue.runWorkLoop(WorkQueue.java:246)
        at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.concurrency.WorkQueue.access$000(WorkQueue.java:50)
        at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.concurrency.WorkQueue$1.call(WorkQueue.java:201)
        at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.concurrency.WorkQueue$1.call(WorkQueue.java:198)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.utils.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:260)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: JRT file system is disabled
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:89)
        at java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$SystemImage.reader(SystemModuleFinders.java:139)
        at java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$ModuleContentSpliterator.<init>(SystemModuleFinders.java:527)
        at java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$SystemModuleReader.list(SystemModuleFinders.java:502)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Hey @Cesar Angiolucci
I am facing the same issue with the same version of Spring Boot (3.1.3)

Comment: It's trying to invoke a method `list()` on this line `at io.github.classgraph.ModuleReaderProxy.list(ModuleReaderProxy.java:107)`

`final Object /* Stream<String> */ resourcesStream = ReflectionUtils
                .invokeMethod(/* throwException = */ true, moduleReader, "list");`

The `moduleReader` is of type `java.lang.AutoCloseable` an interface and I have no idea the specific concrete class the `moduleReader` is

Comment: @Kihats i suspect it could be something to do with the springdoc-openapi, although im using its latest version (that supposedly should work fine). Are you using it also? Ill try to remove its dependency and code from the app and try again.

Comment: Yeah, I have it as a dependency but I don't really have to use it. Let me try removing it

Comment: Hey @Cesar, did you find a solution for this issue? I removed the dependency but still the error persists.

Comment: Hi @Kihats, yes actually i did resolve this specific issue (but now another one appeared). In my case, i had an internal dependency that was using and older version of a swagger dependency, in my case "io.springfox.springfox-swagger-ui". I updated that project, changing that dependenc to the springdoc-openapi. Now, im facing another issue with the ModelMapper that im trying to resolve.